# How do I return false if the typeof a function is equal to undefined?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is there a way to display a message or to return false if the type of an object or function is undefined? It seems as though if an object or function is not present, there's no way to display an error message on screen, but rather the error appears in the Web Console.

Answer (score 3):

This should help:

```
if (typeof foo === "undefined") {
    // foo is undefined
}
```

Alternatively (see [Otto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123156/535871)), you can also use:

```
if (foo === void(0)) {
    // foo is undefined
}
```

You should *not* use `if (foo === undefined)` because (as [Alnitak points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123084/535871)), the global property `undefined` can have a non-default value in some browsers (as of JavaScript 1.8.5—Firefox 4—it is a read-only property).

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` operator will give you the type of a variable, or the string `"undefined"` if the variable is not defined.

```
if (typeof myvar === 'undefined') {
    // it's not defined
}
```

or, if you want a boolean:

```
var itsDefined = (typeof myvar !== 'undefined');
```

This is nominally safer than testing:

```
if (var === undefined)
```

because on some browsers `undefined` may be overwritten.

Comment: Regarding the latter, you can insulate against `undefined` being overwritten by using `void(0)` instead. See [Otto's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13123156/535871).

Answer (score 1):

(obligatory answer including overkill third-party library)

[Underscore.js _.isUndefined()](http://underscorejs.org/#isUndefined)

Which interestingly uses a slightly different method than the other answers provided here:

```
_.isUndefined = function(obj) {
    return obj === void 0;
  };
)
```

Comment: Nice. This is the same as `return obj === undefined;` except that it is immune to code that assigns a non-default value to `undefined`. It's probably much more efficient than doing a `typeof` look-up followed by a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Before you access any methods or grandchildren properties of a variable, you should check whether it is defined using either a `typeof` check (`typeof x==="undefined"`), or a try catch:

```
try{
    x.method();
}catch(e){
    /*You could check the error message to see if the exception was thrown because x is undefined.*/
}
```